# Function "shared neighbors distribution" in igraph

Tags: networkx, igraph

I wonder if someone could give me some clue about writing a function like "shared neighbors distribution", given clusters. I found this feature in Cytoscape NetworkAnalyzer very informative for my research purpose. Since I have many clusters to analyze, it would be handy to write a script for this job. Suggestions using igraph, networkx, etc are welcomed. Thank you very much!

For example:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
E   B
E   A
B   D
B   F
B   C
A   C
A   F
A   D")

library(igraph)
graph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist,directed=F)
plot(graph)
```

We would see a graph like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS55g.png)

Either two of the Nodes (C, D, E, F) shared Nodes A and B. That is 6 times.
Nodes A and B shared Nodes (C, D, E, F).
In total, the summary should like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clO1z.png)

Instead of writing a loop (to get the neighbors for each vertex, and compare them), I wonder if there are better solutions.

Comment: Hello.  In order to help, can you tell us what sort of input this function will need and what the output would be?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks@Joel, I've edit my question a bit. Briefly, input is a graph, output will be a distribution of number of shared neighbors.

Comment: I have one idea like this: convert the graph into adjacency matrix `matrix <- get.adjacency(graph, type=c("both"))
` Then we sort the matrix by  contents of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Networkx has no built-in functions for this problem so you should do it manually. Moreover, if it had, these functions used node loops inside them. So node loop is actually an optimal or sub-optimal solution. For your code you can use Python defaultdicts to make it simplier:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ("E", "B"),
    ("E", "A"),
    ("B", "D"),
    ("B", "F"),
    ("B", "C"),
    ("A", "C"),
    ("A", "F"),
    ("A", "D")
])
snd = defaultdict(int)
for n1 in G.nodes:
    for n2 in G.nodes:
        len_nbrs = len(set(G.neighbors(n1)) & set(G.neighbors(n2)))
        if len_nbrs:
            snd[len_nbrs] += 1
snd
```

So `snd` will looks like it:

```
defaultdict(int, {2: 16, 4: 4})
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will upvote/accept my answer :)

Comment: But when I use this for my example network, the result seems not correct. It returns `defaultdict(int, 
{0: 8})`

Comment: Do you have directed or undirected graph?

Comment: undirected graph@vurmux

Comment: Can you add your graph to question, please?

Comment: I have posted the edgelist in my question :)

Comment: Thanks @vurmux for the effort, I changed a bit your codes, now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @vurmux for the framework and idea. I just adjusted pair combinations, to avoid self-pairs, duplicates etc. Then we get the correct answer. Great. Cheers!

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ("E", "B"),
    ("E", "A"),
    ("B", "D"),
    ("B", "F"),
    ("B", "C"),
    ("A", "C"),
    ("A", "F"),
    ("A", "D")
])

snd = defaultdict(int)
l =G.nodes()
comb =combinations(l,2) # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
for i in list(comb):
    len_nbrs = len(set(G.neighbors(i[0])) & set(G.neighbors(i[1])))
    if len_nbrs:
        snd[len_nbrs] += 1

snd
```

Now we have:

```
defaultdict(int, {2: 6, 4: 1})
```